# C Program Problems with Loops

Tags: c

I'm very new to programming and currently working on a program (it is no where near done) but I cannot figure out how and why this won't work.  I must be missing something with the 'if' and 'else'

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to the ROBOT GAME!\n"
           "Please enter the column of your starting point. Keep numbers in the range of one to three.\n");

    int a, b;
    if(1<=a<=3);
    {
        scanf("%i", &a);
    }
    else 
       {
        printf("Sorry try again.");
       }

    printf("Please enter the row of your starting point.  Keep numbers in the range of one to three.\n");
    if(1>=b<=3);
        scanf("%i", &b);
    printf("What is your next move? Pick\n"
           "1.Right\n"
           "2.Left\n"
           "3.Up\n"
           "4.Down\n");

}
```

Comment: please read a basic C tutorial.

Comment: `C Program Problems with Loops` where is loop?? [Need to learn basic about `C`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_introduction.htm)

Comment: remove `;` after `if(<=2=3)`

Comment: If you're going to post code to SO that doesn't compile, you must at least include the error message you get. "won't work" is not adequate.

Answer (score 1):

**First Bug**

```
int a, b;
if(1<=a<=3);
```

How can you check `a` in `if` condition even it not initialized?. First Fix it by initializing value to `a` and `b` ( with `1`) Then go for to fix **Second Bug**

**Second Bug**

```
if(1<=a<=3);
```

Remove `;` after `if` condition then go for Fix **Third Bug**

**Third Bug**

```
if(1<=a<=3);
```

is not suppose to do what you want. it should

```
if(a>= 1 && a <= 3)
```

Now same is true for `if(1>=b<=3);` Follow every above steps to fix this.

**Fourth Bug**

You have `int main(void)`. So need to `return 0` at end of `main`

Answer (score 1):

Also defining variables but not declaring them is a bad habit.

```
int a, b;
```

Does not assign any value into them and you can't be sure what they will contain. Better would be

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are *lots* of problems here. Firstly, this doesn't mean what you think it means:

```
1<=a<=3
```

Instead, you need

```
1 <=a && a <= 3
```

Also, don't follow the `if` statement with a semicolon:

```
if(1<=a<=3);
           ^
```

On top of that, you need to perform your `scanf()` *before* you check that the value is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if(1<=a<=3);` write `if(a>= 1 && a <= 3)`
same for `if(1>=b<=3);` write `if(b>=1 && b<=3)`

and no semicolon. Just check if else syntax in that programming language. Its is very basic to know.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how measure range in programming. If you want to measure

you have to use `AND` operator.

like

```
if(a>=1 && a<=3) {

}
```

But this won't work here. There is no assignment for `a` and `b`. You have to assign some value to a and b. First read some basic tutorial how `if` and `loop` work in C. Then it will be easy. :)