# Trouble understanding loops

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I am new to C programming and I am having trouble grasping how to use both the `while` and `if` functions in C programming.

At the moment I have this rough attempt at starting my program.  I am currently getting the error message 'expected expression' where I have my 'if statement', but I believe there is more wrong to the code in that it is not going to do what I am looking for.

Ideally I want to make it so that the user will continue to get the same error message until they correctly enter a number from 1-3 and then as soon as they enter a correct number it will then store it and move on to the next steps.  Sorry I am very new at this and I keep getting confused by all the different tutorials that I am reading on looping and if statements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to the ROBOT GAME!\n"
           "To help you visualize draw a three by three board on a piece of paper.\n"
           "Please enter the column of your starting point.\n"
            "Keep numbers in the range of one to three.\n");
    int a;
    scanf("%i", &a);
    while(a<1||a>3)
    {
        printf("Error: Sorry try again.\n"
               "Please enter the column of your starting point.\n");
        int a;
        scanf("%i", &a);
        break;

        if(a=>1 && a<=3)
            printf("Please enter the row of your starting point.  Keep numbers in the range of one to three.\n");

        int b;
        scanf("%i", &b);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `if` statement needs opening and closing braces (i.e., `{` and `}`). Otherwise, you *conditionally* print the message, but *unconditionally* take the input.

Comment: That `break` will always be used. Switch off your computer, take a pencil and a piece of paper, and draw a flowchart first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Program Problems with Loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945438/c-program-problems-with-loops)

Comment: My suggestion for you is to try to do one thing at a time. Instead of reading bot the row and column, try writing a smaller program that only reads just the row first and then prints it back to you.

Comment: this line: scanf("%i", &a); should be: scanf("%d", &a);  Note the use of the %d format descriptor.

Comment: The second   int a; hides the first   int a;, so the second   int a; needs to be removed.

Comment: The code contains plenty of effort to verify the value of 'a' but no code to verify the value of 'b'.  Also the int b; needs to be moved to the next line after the first   int a;, so it can be seen in the rest of your code.

Comment: You will probably want to re-arrange your code so the same variable, for instance 'a' is always read by the same line of code.  I  suggest two while loops, first loop for the variable 'a' and the second loop for the variable 'b'.

Answer (score 1):

Though your program is wrong nevertheless the error message means that you have to substitute `=>` for `>=` in the condition of the if statement

```
if(a=>1 && a<=3)
```

That is there must be

```
if(a >= 1 && a<=3)
     ^^^^
```

The code can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "Welcome to the ROBOT GAME!\n"
            "To help you visualize draw a three by three board on a piece of paper.\n"
            "Please enter the column of your starting point.\n"
            "Keep numbers in the range of one to three.\n" );
    int a;

    scanf( "%i", &a );

    while ( a < 1 || a > 3 )
    {
        printf( "Error: Sorry try again.\n"
                "Please enter the column of your starting point.\n" );

        scanf( "%i", &a );
    }

    int b;

    printf( "Please enter the row of your starting point.  Keep numbers in the range of one to three.\n" );

    scanf( "%i", &b );

    while ( b < 1 || b > 3 )
    {
        printf( "Error: Sorry try again.\n"
                "Please enter the row of your starting point.\n" );

        scanf( "%i", &b );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the *break*

and use

```
if(a <= 1 && a <=3)
```

instead of

```
if(a =< 1 && a <=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your source code in order to do what you want, but i would advise you to try and rewrite the program by using the do{}while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to the ROBOT GAME!\n"
           "To help you visualize draw a three by three board on a piece of paper.\n"
           "Please enter the column of your starting point.\n"
            "Keep numbers in the range of one to three.\n");
    int a,b;
    scanf("%i", &a);
    while(a<1||a>3)
    {
        printf("Error: Sorry try again.\n"
               "Please enter the column of your starting point.\n");
        scanf("%i", &a);
    }
    printf("Please enter the row of your starting point.  Keep numbers in the range of one to three.\n");
    scanf("%i", &b);
    while(b<1||b>3)
    {
        printf("Error: Sorry try again.\n"
               "Please enter the row of your starting point.\n");
        scanf("%i", &b);
    }
}
```